# Need script to loop through stock ticker list, copy resulting output, and paste output to separate sheet within workbook

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me create the following Google sheets script:

I have three sheets named `tickers` , `data` , `results` within a single workbook.

Currently, I manually enter a stock symbol into cell `b9` in the `data` sheet. The sheet then retrieves data (takes around 30 seconds to retrieve data from google finance, run formulas and return data into range `F2:AU2` within the same data sheet.

Request: Create a script to `loop` through a list of 40 stock symbols from the `ticker` sheet (range `B2:B40`), paste 1 symbol at a time into cell `b9` in the `data` sheet, wait for google finance API to run, and then `copy` the results generated in range `F2:AU2`, and pasting those results into the `results` tab, 1 row at a time, until 40 rows of data is produced to correspond with the 40 stock ticker list mentioned earlier.

Can anyone help me with this request? I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi Steve, please add the code that you already tried to write, otherwise it'll be difficult to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code adds a menu item called "Update Stocks" next to the "Help" menu, which provides triggers to run the script and clear all rows of the results tab except for the header row (row 1).  I also added "Ticker" & "Run Date" columns to the "results tab."  Let me know if this is what you are seeking.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Stocks')
    .addItem('UPDATE STOCKS', 'getNewPrices')
    .addItem('Clear Data','clearData')
    .addToUi();
};

function getNewPrices() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const tickerSheet = ss.getSheetByName('tickers');
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  const resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('results');
  let data;


  let myListOfTickers = tickerSheet.getRange('B2:B40').getValues().filter(String).sort();

  myListOfTickers.forEach(ticker => {
    dataSheet.getRange('B9').setValue(ticker[0]);
    data = dataSheet.getRange('F2:AU2').getValues()[0];
    pasteData(resultsSheet, data, ticker);
  });
};

function pasteData(resultsSheet,data, ticker){
  let nextRow = resultsSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //  set timezone to your timezone
  //  https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a
  //
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  let timeZone = "America/New_York";
  //let timeZone = "America/Detroit";
  //let timeZone = "America/Chicago";
  //let timeZone = "America/Denver";
  //let timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";

  resultsSheet.getRange(nextRow,1).setValue(ticker);
  resultsSheet.getRange(nextRow,2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),timeZone,"MM/dd/yyy"));

  data.forEach((datum,index) => {
    resultsSheet.getRange(nextRow,index + 3,1,1).setValue(datum);
  });
};

function clearData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('results');
  const range = resultsSheet.getRange(2,1,resultsSheet.getLastRow(),resultsSheet.getLastColumn());
  range.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, James. Your solution works very well. Out of gratitude for your help, I will email you a copy of the finished spreadsheet for your own personal use. If you'd like a copy, just email me at stevemyerstrader@gmail.com